# Integrating Dagster with Django ORM

Tags: python, etl

I want to integrate Dagster into ongoing Django project. Dagster runs out of Django context and eventually there is no way to directly access django ORM without calling `django.setup()` somewhere, I did it in **init** of my app., but this is not acceptable because it breaks app execution (like `runserver`)

Comment: Try asking this question on stackoverflow. Here we talk mostly about more science-related stuff.

Comment: if anyone is interested, link to the SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048161/integrating-dagster-with-django